# Batch program to delete files with different extentions

Tags: file

I would like to know how to write a batch file that will delete files with extensions identified by the user, so the code will need a user input parameter capability.
Anyone know of an existing one or how I should approach this?

Comment: How is this different than the user typing 'del *.ext'? Are you only concerned with Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WIndows, PowerShell can do this.

get-children -Filter *.whatever | delete

Not sure of the syntax here.  You'll have to check it out.

You can also use del *.whatever /s from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

del *.txt
```

Save this in `deltext.bat`, and all the `.txt` files will be deleted in that directory. If you wanna delete `.3gp` files then write:

```
del *.3gp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the key to your question!

```
DEL "C:\(you can select specific file path here)*(here is the part you put what extension to move)*"
```

This should work, if not then tell me the error message, and i will be happy to help.